# newton method using python

Tags: python, numerical-methods, newtons-method

```
p= lambda x: 3 * x**3 - 5.03 * x**2 - 1.95 * x + 0.02

dp = lambda x: 9 * x**2 - 10.06 * x - 1.95
x0 = -1
tol = 10**-4
max_iter = 100

def newton_method(f, df, x0, tol, max_iter=100):
    for i in range(max_iter):
        fx = f(x0)
        dfx = df(x0)
        if df==0 and dfx!=0 :
            raise Exception('division by 0')
        
        elif fx==0:
            return i, x0
        
        x = x0 - fx/dfx
        
        if abs(x-x0) <=tol:
              return i, x0
        x0 = x
    raise ValueError("The newton method doesn't converge after {} iterations".format(max_iter))

c,r = newton_method(p, dp , x0, tol, max_iter)
print("Approssimazione:", r,c)
```

the function looks like that works well if i put a starting point of -1 or 0, but if i put a value near 5 ( another zero is circa 5.3) the function "converges" to 2 that is far  from being a a solution.

it is even odder if i put `x_0=2` because the function does 0 iterations and regards 2 as a solution no matter which tolerance i put, it is like the function shuts when it checks if the absolute value is lesser or equal than the tolerance, but if i try to compute the `x` term at `i=0` the result isn't lesser or equal than any  tolerance, could someone help me to understand what's wrong with the algorithm?

Comment: Why are you surprised about the results for input 2? `p(2)` is 0.0000000000000009055 so unless you have tolerance that is much smaller, 2 will be regarded a solution. Why do you call this "far from being a solution"?

Comment: because 2 is a lot far from 5, and if i start the algorithm at 5 it gives 2 as output still, and i tried with big tollerances like 1e-20 but it still doesnt work

Comment: My question is why you write *"2 that is far from being a a solution."* Do you dispute it is a *very* close solution? I don't understand your reasoning in the "it is even odder" paragraph. What did you expect to happen when you input 2?

Comment: Perhaps the whole point of this exercise with this particular cubic polynomial is to illustrate the limitations of Newton's method and figure out how to overcome them.

Comment: Also, you write *"another zero is circa 5.3"*... I don't see what you mean here. Certainly f(5) is nowhere near zero... I think your question is based on some huge misunderstanding about the function. Have you plotted it?

Comment: i mistaken the values over wolfram, just my bad

Comment: What does `df==0` mean? You compare a function handle to a numerical value, it makes no sense. // Comparing floating-point results to exact zero gives an event with probability zero. Use some accuracy or error threshold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph for the function ()=3³−5.03²−1.95+0.02 looks like this (produced by [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=find+roots+3*x%5E3-5.03*x%5E2-1.95*x%2B0.02)):

[image]

The roots are at:

- = −1/3
- = 1/100
- = 2

The results you get from running your function are as expected.

Notably, when you start with 5, it is expected that the process converges to 2, which *is* a solution. On the other hand 5.3 is not a zero-point of this function.

Comment: my bad i only wrote the function wrong either on wolfram and on here